# MS-Access union query syntax error

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, union

**Goal**: When generating a top 3 customer result, include a sum value in it

**Problem**: syntax error in union query

```
SELECT Sum(dbo_SO_SalesHistory.DollarsSold) AS SumDollarsSold, "ALLE" As dbo_SO_SalesHistory.CustomerNo  
FROM dbo_SO_SalesHistory 
WHERE ((dbo_SO_SalesHistory.[CustomerNo]) IN ("MIN","ALLE","BROO","OMP")) 
UNION
SELECT TOP 9  
Sum(DollarsSold), CustomerNo 
FROM dbo_SO_SalesHistory 
WHERE ((dbo_SO_SalesHistory.CustomerNo) NOT IN ("MIN"","BROO", "ALLE", "OMP")) GROUP BY dbo_SO_SalesHistory.CustomerNo ORDER BY 1 DESC;
```

So I test each individual query to pinpoint which query is wrong

The first part of query, gives me

The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect.

```
SELECT Sum(dbo_SO_SalesHistory.DollarsSold) AS SumDollarsSold, "PHOALLE" As dbo_SO_SalesHistory.CustomerNo 
FROM dbo_SO_SalesHistory
WHERE ((dbo_SO_SalesHistory.CustomerNo) IN ("PHOMIN","PHOALLE","PHOBROO","PHOMP"));
```

Any advice regarding the errors would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `"MIN""` is a typo (extra `"`)

Comment: @AlexK. thank you so much! I did double-check but didn't notice it. Thank you. I still get the error from the first part of the query.

Comment: Try `As [dbo_SO_SalesHistory.CustomerNo]` (the dot is not valid in an unescaped alias)

Comment: @AlexK. Yay Thank you so much! Problem solved! Thank you so so much! Would you please answer the question that way I can green-check it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of issues:

- `"MIN""` is a typo (extra `"`)
- `.. As dbo_SO_SalesHistory.CustomerNo` is not a valid column alias due to the `.`, to escape it: `.. As [dbo_SO_SalesHistory.CustomerNo]`